# What integral is required to calculate $\mathbb{P}(t\leq T_1\leq T_2)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be independent Exponential random variables with paramaters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively, and let $T=\min\{T_1,T_2\}$. Show that the probability that $T=T_1$ is $\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$, and that this is independent of the value of $T$.

So far I have completed the first part:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(T=T_1)&=\mathbb{P}(\min\{T_1,T_2\}=T_1)=\mathbb{P}(T_2\geq T_1)\\
&=\int_0^\infty f_{T_1}(x)\mathbb{P}(T_2\geq x)dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}e^{-\lambda_2x}dx\\
&=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.
\end{align*}
$$

However I am somewhat stuck for the second part of this. I know this is probably easy, but I just figure out what integrals to set up. This is my attempt:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(T=T_1\land T\geq x)&=\mathbb{P}(t\leq T_1\leq T_2)\\
&=\int_{T_1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(t\leq T_1)f_{T_2}(x)dx\tag{I am very unsure of this step}\\
&=\int_y^\infty\int_t^\infty f_{T_1}(y)f_{T_2}(x)dxdy\tag{I am also unsure of this step}
\end{align*}
$$
I thought maybe this was the integral I wanted to set up to calculate this, but then when I followed the calculation through, it got me nowhere, which made me suspicious that I had set up the wrong integral. So then I checked the solutions and it just had
$$
\mathbb{P}(t\leq T_1\leq T_2)=\int_{x=t}^\infty\int_{y=x}^\infty f_{T_1}(x)f_{T_2}(y)dydx.
$$
Obviously, this gives the right answer, but I just can't see how the did this step? Could anyone explain where these integrals came from and where the limits of the integration came from? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As always, if $X$ is a continuous r.v., $$\mathbb P\{X\in A\}=\int_A f_X(x)\,\mathrm d x.$$ In your case, Set $A=\{(u,v)\leq t\leq u\leq v\}$. Then $$\mathbb P\{t\leq T_1\leq T_2\}=\mathbb P\{(T_1,T_2)\in A\}=\iint_Af_{T_1,T_2}(u,v)\,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d u=\int_{t}^\infty \int_u^\infty f_{T_1,T_2}(u,v)\,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d u.$$

Comment: ($\uparrow$ read: **absolutely** continous.) Also $f_{T_1,T_2}(u,v)=f_{T_1}(u)\,f_{T_2}(v)$ (by independence) and Fubini's theorem should be stated.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by $\{(u,v)\leq t\leq u\leq v\}$?

Comment: Mistake. Should be $\{(u,v)\in \mathbb R^2\mid t\leq u\leq v\}$